# Invertible Composition of Maps

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that if a composition of two linear maps is invertible, the two maps must also be invertible?

Comment: That holds only under some circumstances. Are the maps endomorphisms of a finite-dimensional vector space?

Comment: Yes, I meant to add it's a composition of operators on some finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: Since $f \circ g$ is invertible, you know that $g$ is injective, and $f$ surjective. For operators on a finite-dimensional space, the dimension formula (rank nullity in American, iirc) does the rest.

Comment: This just corroborates one of the fundamental facts of mathematics: Everything is secretly Rank-Nullity.

Answer (score 0):

This is true in finite dimensions (see your third comment "Since $f\circ g$ ... "). This is false in countable dimensions. For example, on $l^2$ let $f$, $g$ be the left- and right-shift operators, respectively. Then clearly $f\circ g$ is the identity map, but $f$ is not injective, and $g$ is not surjective!!